# PHP website creator site - duplication issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2, virtualhost

**Background**
I'm creating a website in PHP that allows users to register and set up their own website on a subdomain branching from my site.

For example, if you sign up you have your own directory on the server and a subdomain.
EG: mysub.mysite.com == mysite.com/mysub

I'm also configuring VirtualHost so that users can set an A name record to the site so they can use their domain etc.

**Problem**
Every time a user signs up a script I wrote is executed that creates a directory on the server for that user and then copies across a set of files (a base stylesheet, index file etc). These files are the same for every single user. That means that every user that registers is going to have the exact same index.php file (the content is modified based on their ID pulled from a DB, eg the title of the site). I obviously don't want to have to copy these files across for every new user because that's a huge waste of space.

Is there any way I can somehow reference the file from a single location (remembering the VirtualHost setup) so that each user doesn't need their own in their directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need the index file for sure, and if you are using php, you can set a script inside `require_once('./index.php')` this might be a as that way every single users default index page will load your template in an upper directory.

If you structure is mysite.com/users/danny/ and you put your default template index.php in the users folder, and use that script in danny's folders index.php, it will work.